# Projection Problem on Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle-spatial, coordinate-system

I would like to transform SDO_GEOMETRY from WGS84 projection to my custom projection in Oracle Database.

Details for custom projection is as follows:

```json
+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.5 +lat_2=37.5 +lat_0=25 +lon_0=36 +x_0=1003827.11 +y_0=-1183453.08 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

PROJCS["Customized Lambert",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",40.5],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",37.5],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",25],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",36],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1003827.11],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-1183453.08],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]'
```

Running SDO_CS.VALIDATE_WKT for custom projection returns TRUE.
But,

```sql
SELECT SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(29 41)',8307),1000003006) FROM DUAL;
```

returns with ORA-13282 & ORA-06512 errors.

What is the problem here ?

Comment: What database version do you use ? And how did you define this custom system - what SQL did you use for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the projection name. In Oracle, the proper name for the 2SP Lambert Conformal Conic projection is "Lambert Conformal Conic" (notice: no "2SP", spaces instead of underscores).

The following definition will work:

```
'PROJCS["Customized Lambert",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert Conformal Conic"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",40.5],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",37.5],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",25],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",36],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1003827.11],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-1183453.08],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]'
```

When defining a new SRID using the well-known text notation, Oracle is flexible in the way you name the projection parameters (capitalized or not, underscores or spaces) but is stricter for the actual names of the projections.

```
SQL> SELECT SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(29 41)',8307),1000003006) FROM DUAL;

SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(2941)',8307),1000003006)(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 1000003006, SDO_POINT_TYPE(415303.239, 628045.739, NULL), NULL, NULL)

1 row selected.
```